# Is there a way to truncate ostream?

Tags: c++, ostream

I have small class that write to `std::ostream`, but it need to reset the file to zero length.

I do something like this:

```
namespace config{
    constexpr std::ios::openmode MODE = std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc;
}

std::ofstream file_data{filename, config::MODE};
//...
file_data = {filename, config::MODE};
```

This works, because it call `std::ofstream` d-tor, but there should be better way?

Comment: Yes [resize_file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file).

Comment: _"there should be better way?"_ -- There is nothing wrong with the approach you show here.